# Kensington lock for iPhone

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation

I'm going to a conference where there be a booth for my company to showcase our product. I'm bringing an iPhone which will be part of the product demonstration.

Now is there any product out there that can help secure the device from theft? I'm not sure where to buy those cables attached to phones at BestBuy and I'd like to be able to remove the cable once the show is over.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targus makes a line of security locks for iPhones and iPods:

- [Targus Desktop Security Lock for iPod® (ASP06US)](http://www.targus.com/us/productdetail.aspx?sku=ASP06US)
- [Targus Mobile Security Lock for iPod® (ASP07US)](http://www.targus.com/us/productdetail.aspx?sku=ASP07US)